# Free running down counter in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I recently started to try my hands at matlab and simulink , was implementing a counter in simulink , and implemented a simple up counter which counts upto 50
[image: Free Running Up Counter]

now i want to implement the simplest down counter , but i found my logic for implementing down counter in simulink is quite big , can anyone suggest a simpler logic for down counter with the explanation .
[image: Down Counter from 10 to 0]

Comment: There's nothing wrong (or bad) about your implementation.  Even if you look at the implementation of the [Free Running Counter](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/counterfreerunning.html) block (by looking under its mask) you'll see that it is done in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Phil , what i am more interested into, is finding out if there is a more simpler way to implement the down counter like the simplicity level of the up counter simulink model drawn above.

Comment: There are several alternatives, but my comment was meant to imply that if there was a universally better way of doing it then The MathWorks would have used it in their implementation, and they have not.  If you don't like the way it looks, then put a mask on top (as The MathWorks have done).

Comment: the logic for up counter is quite simple however thats not the case for down counter , i am more interested in finding out a simpler logic for down counter just like the up counter modeled above and not at all worried about the looks , it would be really helpful if you can suggest other alternative simpler models for the down counter.

Comment: @beastboy what is the purpose of the switch? This makes the output 10 if the counter is less than zero. Is this really necessary for a simple down counter? Why not just set the initial value of the delay block to 10?